# Efecto de Icon con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Estoy trabajando con Materialize usando acordeones collapsible y necesito que un icon se anime cuando el acordeón este abierto básicamente de esta forma.

si el acordeón está cerrado que el icono este de esta forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si el acordeón se abre que el icono cambie a esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$('#probando').on('click', function () {
                $('#icon-effect').css("transform", "rotate(180deg)")
            });
```

```html
<li id="probando">
                            <a class="collapsible-header">
                                <i class="material-icons">folder_special</i>Certificados
                                <i class="material-icons right" style="margin-right: 0;" id="icon-effect">expand_more</i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="collapsible-body">
                                <ul id="Opciones_Trabajador" runat="server">
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

Ando intentando con Jquery y solo logro que se ponga hacia arriba, también requiero que cuando se de clic en otro collapsible el icon flecha regrese a su estado original.

Dejo lo que llevo.

Gracias

Comment: revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472456/materializecss-collapsible-active-change-icon

Comment: Sirvio bastante lo logre sacar con CSS

Comment: @AlexMachado si lo conseguiste solucionar, por favor añade una respuesta y márcala como aceptada cuando pase el tiempo requerido.

Answer (score 1):

Logre darle solución añadiendo un elemento `active` despues de la etiqueta que necesitaba el efecto de giro.

```css
.sidenav .collapsible li.active .right {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```